# Show folders/files in TreeView ( VB.NET 2008 )

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

I need to create one treeview and to have there all of my directories and files from one path.

I cant compile this code. The problem is on this line : mnodedirectory.nodes.add(mfilesnode)

```
' get the directory representing this node

Dim mnodedirectory As IO.DirectoryInfo
mnodedirectory = New IO.DirectoryInfo(e.Node.Tag.ToString)
        ' add each subdirectory from the file system to the expanding node as a child node
For Each mdirectory As IO.DirectoryInfo In mnodedirectory.GetDirectories
    ' declare a child treenode for the next subdirectory
    Dim mdirectorynode As New TreeNode
    ' store the full path to this directory in the child treenode's tag property
    mdirectorynode.Tag = mdirectory.FullName
    ' set the child treenodes's display text
    mdirectorynode.Text = mdirectory.Name
    ' add a dummy treenode to this child treenode to make it expandable
    mdirectorynode.Nodes.Add("*temp*")
    ' add this child treenode to the expanding treenode
    e.Node.Nodes.Add(mdirectorynode)
Next

For Each mfile As IO.FileInfo In mnodedirectory.GetFiles
    Dim mfilesnode As New TreeNode
    mfilesnode.Tag = mfile.FullName
    mfilesnode.Text = mfile.Name
    mnodedirectory.nodes.add(mfilesnode)
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please search first before ask again and again [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373628/vb-net-2008-not-recognizing-path-getfilename-method/33373968#33373968)

```
'Don't forget to import this
Imports System.IO

'Declare these
Private Enum ItemType
    Drive
    Folder
    File
End Enum

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each drive As DriveInfo In DriveInfo.GetDrives
        Dim node As TreeNode = _
            file_view_tree.Nodes.Add(drive.Name)
        node.Tag = ItemType.Drive
        node.Nodes.Add("FILLER")
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub file_view_tree_BeforeExpand(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventArgs) Handles file_view_tree.BeforeExpand
    Dim currentNode As TreeNode = e.Node
    currentNode.Nodes.Clear()
    Try
        'Now go get all the files and folders
        Dim fullPathString As String = currentNode.FullPath

        'Handle each folder
        For Each folderString As String In _
            Directory.GetDirectories(fullPathString)
            Dim newNode As TreeNode = _
            currentNode.Nodes.Add(Path.GetFileName(folderString))
            Dim x As String = Path.GetFileName("")
            newNode.Tag = ItemType.Folder
            newNode.Nodes.Add("FILLER")
        Next

        'Handle each file
        For Each fileString As String In _
            Directory.GetFiles(fullPathString)
            'Get just the file name portion (without the path) :
            Dim newNode As TreeNode = _
            currentNode.Nodes.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileString))
            newNode.Tag = ItemType.File
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You've used mnodedirectory as the name of your TreeView, where it is the name of a DirectoryInfo object.

This is an example called from a button click, with c:\temp\ as the given starting directory

```
Private Sub TestButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button39.Click

    TestTreeView.Nodes.Clear()
    Dim ndParent As TreeNode = TestTreeView.Nodes.Add("c:\temp\")
    ndParent.Tag = "c:\temp"
    'add a child node to allow 'expand' to fire
    ndParent.Nodes.Add("*temp*")

End Sub

Private Sub populateFilesAndFolders(parentNode As TreeNode, startingPath As String)

    Dim inspectDirectoryInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(startingPath)
    ' add each subdirectory from the file system to the expanding node as a child node
    For Each directoryInfoItem As IO.DirectoryInfo In inspectDirectoryInfo.GetDirectories
        ' declare a child treenode for the next subdirectory
        Dim directoryTreeNode As New TreeNode
        ' store the full path to this directory in the child treenode's tag property
        directoryTreeNode.Tag = directoryInfoItem.FullName
        ' set the child treenodes's display text
        directoryTreeNode.Text = directoryInfoItem.Name
        ' add a dummy treenode to this child treenode to make it expandable
        directoryTreeNode.Nodes.Add("*temp*")
        ' add this child treenode to the expanding treenode
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(directoryTreeNode)
        populateFilesAndFolders(directoryTreeNode, directoryInfoItem.FullName)

    Next

    For Each fileItem As IO.FileInfo In inspectDirectoryInfo.GetFiles
        Dim fileNode As New TreeNode
        fileNode.Tag = fileItem.FullName
        fileNode.Text = fileItem.Name
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(fileNode)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub TestTreeView_BeforeExpand(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventArgs) Handles TestTreeView.BeforeExpand
    Try
        populateFilesAndFolders(e.Node, e.Node.Tag.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please give me a help ?

Comment: What is the name of your TreeView control?

Comment: It works for me. Inside which event handler are you putting the code? In the above example it is executed once from a button click event. It looks like you have the code into one of the TreeView click / select events?

Comment: On BeforeExpand TreeView event

Comment: Access to the path 'c:\Documents and Settings' is denied.

Here i dont have any folder with this name ...

Comment: c:\temp is just my example. Change the path code to suit your environment.