# Get all the folders and sub-folders and files in a directory Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

how can i get all the folders and sub-folders and files in a specific path directory?,

example:

```
+ folder1
 - exe1
 + folder2
  - exe1
  - exe2
  + folder3
   - exe1

+ folder2
 - exe1

+ folder3

+ folder4
```

im using right now on:

```
Sub GetDirectories(ByVal StartPath As String)
        For Each Dir As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(StartPath)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Dir)
            ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles(StartPath))
            ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles(Dir))
        Next
    End Sub
```

and:

```
Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)

        For Each path In files

            For Each Dir As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path)
                GetDirectories(path)
            Next

        Next
```

but it not giving me all the files from the other sub-folders.

**Edit:
using with listbox and i want see the full path when drop in the folder and after this giving all the sub folders and files**

Answer (score 0):

You can better use the `TreeView` to get more convenient results.

Simply get a `TreeView` from the ToolBox and use the following code for listing a specific directory and sub-directories (including files):

```
Private Enum ItemType
    Drive
    Folder
    File
End Enum

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim node As TreeNode =
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Hello") ' Specifying Folder Names
    node.Tag = ItemType.Folder
    node.Nodes.Add("FILLER")
End Sub

Private Sub file_view_tree_BeforeExpand(sender As Object, e As TreeViewCancelEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.BeforeExpand

    Dim currentNode As TreeNode = e.Node
    currentNode.Nodes.Clear()

    Try
        'Now go get all the files and folders
        Dim fullPathString As String = currentNode.FullPath

        'Handle each folder
        For Each folderString As String In
            Directory.GetDirectories(fullPathString)

            Dim newNode As TreeNode =
            currentNode.Nodes.Add(Path.GetFileName(folderString))
            Dim x As String = Path.GetFileName("")
            newNode.Tag = ItemType.File
            newNode.Nodes.Add("FILLER")
        Next

        'Handle each file
        For Each fileString As String In
            Directory.GetFiles(fullPathString)
            'Get just the file name portion (without the path) :
            Dim newNode As TreeNode =
                currentNode.Nodes.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileString))
            newNode.Tag = ItemType.File
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

> Note: I've modified [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370064/show-folders-files-in-treeview-vb-net-2008) thread of Stack Overflow and customized as per of your requirement.

[image: TreeView Better Than ListBox]

Comment: the point im using with listbox and i want see the full path when drop in the folder and after this giving all the sub folders and files